# Best way to extend a method of Google library

Tags: java, json, gson, static-libraries

I develop a Java program that using com.google.gson.Gson(gson-2.2.4.jar). The method will throw exception in case date format ISO 8601 (for example: "2015-06-22T09:26:27+0000")

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2015-06-22T09:26:27+0000
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
```

To fix it, I have 2 ways

1. `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX").create();` ==> apply for all gson objects ==> change ~50 positions
2. Extract the library of google as an utility of my program and change the `DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate()` function to handle this error. After that I'll change the import from google library into my utility library ==> change ~ 20 files

What is the best way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this type adapter:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/gson/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/UtcDateTypeAdapter.java

```
    final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new UtcDateTypeAdapter());
    final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```